# Passing a variable to an OpenGL GLSL shader

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, glsl

I'm writing an iPhone app which uses GLSL shaders to perform transformations on textures, but one point that I'm having a little hard time with is passing variables to my GLSL shader.

I've read that it's possible to have a shader read part of the OpenGL state (and I would only need read-only access to this variable), but I'm not sure how that exchange would happen.

In short, I'm trying to get a float value created outside of a fragment shader to be accessible to the fragment shader (whether it's passed in or read from inside the shader).

Thanks for any help/pointers you can provide, it's very appreciated!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

One option is to pass information via uniform variables.

After

```
glUseProgram(myShaderProgram);
```

you can use

```
GLint myUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(myShaderProgram, "myUniform");
```

and for example

```
glUniform1f(myUniformLocation, /* some floating point value here */);
```

In your vertex or fragment shader, you need to add the following declaration:

```
uniform float myUniform;
```

That's it, in your shader you can now access (read-only) the value you passed earlier on via `glUniform1f`.

Of course uniform variables can be any valid GLSL type including complex types such
as arrays, structures or matrices. OpenGL provides a `glUniform` function with the usual suffixes,
appropriate for each type. For example, to assign to a variable of type `vec3`, one would
use `glUniform3f` or `glUniform3fv`.

Note: the value can't be modified during execution of the shader, i.e. in a `glBegin`/`glEnd` block. It is read-only and the same for every fragment/vertex processed.

There are also several tutorials using uniforms, you can find them by googling "glsl uniform variable".

Comment: Can I also pass a variable that differs for each vertex?